# htaccess mod_rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I'm having some trouble with my mod_rewrite rule.  Here's what I have:

```
RewriteRule ^admin ?page=admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^welcome ?page=welcome [NC]
```

This changes URL's as follows:

```
http://localhost/index.php?page=admin -> http://localhost/admin
http://localhost/index.php?page=welcome -> http://localhost/welcome
```

It works, but I only want to write one rule since the page (welcome or admin) is a variable.

What I've tried that won't work:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+) ?page=$1 [NC]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found the solution:  RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]

Comment: And it didn't seem to want to work until I added index.php.  Without it I was getting a mis-configuration error from Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is busted I think.

This guy should get you a bit closer...

RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/?page=$1

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything for me.  I even changed https to http.

Comment: OK, This did the trick for me:    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]